# Google playstore, duplicate declaration of permissions

Tags: android, google-play

Just wanted to do a small update in my app and got this message. Didn't really change much in my gradle/manifest file from the last time i updated.

[image]

Could it be a library conflict?

Answer (score 0):

In order to deal with dublicates as the above you can use the manifest merger. In my case i had to use **tools="replace"** along with my permission which keeps the permission as is and it doesn't rty to merge it with permissions from other libraries.

e.g 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace" />`

[This link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Element-markers-examples) helped me understand the merger better